# How we can add current uid in self table?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am new to flutter,
I want to add the current logged userid in dist_id?
How I can do this in flutter?

I tried

```
Future <void> addCustomer() async{
final User currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
String _generatedPassword = generatePassword(true, true, true, 6);
final User user =(await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: _emailTextFieldController.text, password:_generatedPassword)).user;

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
"uid": user.uid,
"name":_nameTextFieldController.text,
"address":_addressTextFieldController.text,
"pincode":_pincodeTextFieldController.text,
"email":_emailTextFieldController.text,
"mobile_number":_mobilenoTextFieldController.text,
"password":_generatedPassword,
"role": 'Customer',
"dist_id": currentUser.uid
});
}
```

But this is give me previous user id.I want current User id and stored it to the dist_id.

Comment: Could you add the code you are using around that line? I think I know the answer but your question is very vague.I do not understand how you can get the previous user ID since that data is not being stored

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also don't Know how I can get the previous user id. I edited question please check!

Comment: To be honest I do not understand the issue... This seems to be working properly... Which user was signed in while creating document shown on the image?

Comment: @vitooh my current logged user is **fJXySJTyWPY0YsTsn6MA9MWBiMB3** this but I got the previous created userid in dist_id.